# Annotation passed as a parameter in C# method?

Tags: c#, annotations, parameter-passing, square-bracket

I am looking to use the following method, however it is the first time I come across what is listed as the second parameter of the method. What should go there, what does it mean?

[image]

Here is the github repository from which the method comes from:
https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin

Comment: It means its an optional parameter.  So pass something if you want, otherwise its `= null`

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the library, but `ShareOptions.cs` seems pretty well documented: https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin/blob/master/Share/Share.Plugin.Abstractions/ShareOptions.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Platform specific Share Options
/// </summary>
public class ShareOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Android: Gets or sets the title of the app chooser popup.
    /// If null (default) the system default title is used.
    /// </summary>
    public string ChooserTitle { get; set; } = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Tizen: Excluded App Types
    /// </summary>
    public ShareAppControlType ExcludedAppControlTypes { get; set; } = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// iOS: Gets or sets the UIActivityTypes that should not be displayed.
    /// If null (default) the value of <see cref="Plugin.Share.ShareImplementation.ExcludedUIActivityTypes"/> is used.
    /// </summary>
    public ShareUIActivityType[] ExcludedUIActivityTypes { get; set; } = null;    

    /// <summary>
    /// iOS only: Gets or sets the popover anchor rectangle.
    /// If null (default) the option is not used.
    /// </summary>
    public ShareRectangle PopoverAnchorRectangle { get; set; } = null;
}
```